# caffe | Error parsing ... String literals cannot cross line boundaries

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, protocol-buffers, deep-learning, caffe

I would like to fine tune [`bvlc_reference_caffenet`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet) model on my dataset.
I did the following steps:

1. I created lmdb files for the new dataset I had.
2. I downloaded the Pretrained `bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel`.
3. I changed the last layer i.e `"fc8"`, fully connected layer:
   Took the `train_val.prototxt` and  changed the last layer `"fc8"` to `"fc8_tune"`.
4. I changed `num_output` to the right number of output classes trying to predict (i.e 2).
5. I changed `solver.prototxt` according my data
6. I run

   ```
   $TOOLS/caffe train --solver=solver.prototxt --weights=bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel
   ```

but I got the following  error

> ```
> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 363:19: String literals cannot cross line boundaries.
> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 363:18: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "fc8_tune".
> F0531 17:13:33.284981  3670 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /caffe-master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt
> ```

can anyone help me in solving this error?

Comment: Thanku so much...Shai...:)..It's Working.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close a quotation mark (`"`) in your `prototxt` file.
According to the error message

> Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: **363**:19:

you should look around line number 363.

Comment: ....If I want to add new layers...Where should i change in prototxt file.I want to add two more layers to check the performance,how it will perform after adding more layers.Can you please suggest me.

Comment: @BHAV247 add layers at the end of the file

Comment: @BHAV247 this seems like a new question. please post it as such, with all the relevant information and well formatted. thanks.